# I need a certain part of it from the complete string

Tags: c#

This is the complete string I have,

> Set-Cookie: Authsite=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.where2getit.com%2Flogin.html; path=/; domain=my.where2getit.com,**W2GISM=81accd985beefec2b555706ac4ae20eb; path=/; domain=my.where2getit.com; expires=Fri, 20-Feb-2015 05:21:40 GMT**; secure; HttpOnly

I need to get only this part. Is there anything that i can do with split or anything in C# ? Please any help

> W2GISM=81accd985beefec2b555706ac4ae20eb; path=/; domain=my.where2getit.com; expires=Fri, 20-Feb-2015 05:21:40 GMT

Comment: *Based on what logic?* Try `var result = "W2GISM=81accd985beefec2b555706ac4ae20eb; path=/; domain=my.where2getit.com; expires=Fri, 20-Feb-2015 05:21:40 GMT";`. It looks like you need to be using a proper cookie parsing mechanism. What is the context?

Comment: What solutions have you tried? What's not working? Do you have a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? You might look over the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
var url = "Set-Cookie: Authsite=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.where2getit.com%2Flogin.html; path=/; domain=my.where2getit.com,W2GISM=81accd985beefec2b555706ac4ae20eb; path=/; domain=my.where2getit.com; expires=Fri, 20-Feb-2015 05:21:40 GMT; secure; HttpOnly";
var tab = url.Split(',');
var value = string.Concat(tab[1], tab[2].Split(';')[0]);
Console.WriteLine (value);
```

Output:

```
W2GISM=81accd985beefec2b555706ac4ae20eb; path=/; domain=my.where2getit.com; expires=Fri 20-Feb-2015 05:21:40 GMT
```

Answer (score 0):

whats the logic? is domain=my.where2getit.com static ?

use String.Split() based on your string structure and pick the appropriate items from the output array